# Deserialize JSON in c# when the return dataset in not known

Tags: c#, json, linq, asp.net-mvc-4, serialization

I am working on census data and the url for my json is:

http://api.census.gov/data.json

From the above json i want to build the drop down of "title" where "c_dataset" have "acs5". Now the code in my MVC controller is as follows :

```
var yourObject = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<dynamic>(result.ToString());

            foreach (KeyValuePair<string, object> currency in yourObject)
            {
                if (currency.Key == "dataset")
                {
                    foreach (KeyValuePair<string, object> cur in currency.Value)
                    {

                    }
                }
            }
```

the inner most foreach gives me an error that "foreach statement can not operate on variable type 'object' because 'object' does not contain a public definition for 'GetEnumerator' !! i can not deserialize the object in certain class because this json is big. What could be the best way to do this ? Also, i was wondering if i can use the LINQ to query the deserialize object. Thanks in advance.

Comment: 448kb isn't really that big. What happens when you try to deserialize it to a concrete type?

Comment: @JLRishe i meant is big structure to make class i just want deserialize it to create dropdown out of it. how could we do the deserialize  to a concrete type ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your best bet would be to build concrete type(s) that only have the properties you want, ignoring everything else. JSON deserializer will then ignore additional "noise" and only read the properties you specified.

```
// not tested
class CensusDataSet
{
    [JsonProperty("c_dataset")]
    public string[] CDataset { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("title")]
    public string Title { get; set; }
}

class CensusData
{

    [JsonProperty("dataset")]
    public CensusDataSet[] DataSets { get; set; }
}

...
var data = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<CensusData>(content);

foreach (var dataSet in data.DataSets) ...
```

BTW, your title is misleading: what you are trying to do is called **de**serialize.

Comment: Wow, this is so great, works best for me ! i did not know this way. Thanks for this solution.

Comment: Also i wanted to add AccessURL so i added in CensusDataSet but it's coming null in deserialization. What could be the reason ?

Comment: That's because accessURL is not a property of CensusDataSet. It lives inside property "distribution", which is an array of records. You must mimic this hierarchy in your types, you can't expect the deserializer to figure it out for you. You need to create `class Distribution { public string AccessUrl { get; set; }}`, and then add field `Distribution[] Distributions` to `CensusDataSet`. Don't forget proper `JsonProperty(name)` attributes. Once you've done that, you get accessURL as dataSet.Distributions[0].AccessUrl.

Comment: do you know any way(dynamic) we can parse the json without creating the generic classes ?